# How to create empty column with a specific number in dataframe python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am new to python and I want to know how to create empty column with a specific number. Let's say I want to create 20 columns. What I tried:

```
import pandas as pd
num =20 

for i in range(num):
    df = df + pd.DataFrame(columns=['col'+str(i)])
```

But I got the unwanted result:

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [col0, col1, col10, col11, col12, col13, col14, col15, col16, col17, col18, col19, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6, col7, col8, col9]
Index: []
```

Desired result:

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [col0, col1, col2,...,col19]
Index: []
```

How to rectify it? Any help will be much appreciated!

Comment: Why is the result unwanted? What is the desired result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you wish to create an empty dataframe, the solution is to remove the for loop, and use a list comprehension for the column names:

```
import pandas as pd
num =20 
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['col'+str(i) for i in range(num)])
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding dataframes together, let's just create a dictionary with the mappings you'd like, and create one dataframe:

```
data = {"col" + str(i): [] for i in range(20)}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
#Empty DataFrame
#Columns: [col0, col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6, col7, col8, col9, col10, col11, col12, col13, col14, col15, col16, col17, col18, col19]
#Index: []
```